# The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value. SqlException

Tags: c#, datetime

I am a beginner in asp.net. I am using a query :

```
 string num = ("SELECT count(*) from booking WHERE date='" + dt + "' AND start_time='" + stime + "' AND end_time='" + etime + "' AND lid='" + hostloc + "'");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(num, con);

con.Open();

int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

con.Close();
```

Sometimes when i submit my web form it gives me an SqlException :

> "The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range datetime value."

This does not happen always!!
Please, any help is appreciated..
Thank You in advance

Comment: What is the date when it does happen?

Comment: Key trick there: don't concatenate values into command-text. Parameters are strongly typed: they don't get misunderstood

Comment: It is a web form for making a booking. Its value is selected by the the user using ajaxcalenderxtender

Comment: when the error occurs is one of thos date values null perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string num = "SELECT count(*) from booking WHERE date=@dt AND start_time=@stime AND end_time=@etime AND lid=@hostloc";

using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(num, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dt", dt);
    // etc for all params
    con.Open();

    int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Note this assumes `dt` is a `DateTime` etc.

This solves multiple problems, including formatting, localisation and SQL injection.

Comment: string hostloc =DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
string dt = TextBox1.Text;                          Convert.ToDateTime(dt);
string stime = TextBox2.Text;
string etime = TextBox3.Text;                                  string subject = TextBox4.Text;
            string num = ("SELECT count(*) from booking WHERE date='" + dt + "' AND start_time='" + stime + "' AND end_time='" + etime + "' AND lid='" + hostloc + "'");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(num, con);
            con.Open();
            int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            con.Close();

Comment: @user wow, sql injection heaven. If you routinely write data access code like that: **stop immediately**. You need to parameterize. Really.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use parameterized queries for your SQL calls or you might get SQL injected soon enough.

Also you need to convert dt to datetime before you send the variable to the SQL Server in order to avoid such errors, like `Convert.ToDatetime(dt)`.